# Selenium WebDriver FindElement(noSuchElementId) throws TimeoutException instead of NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

With IE 11 and Selenium 2.37 attempting to get an element text with an invalid elementId:

```
TimeSpan pageLoadTimeout = new TimeSpan(HOURS, MINUTES, m_WebPageSettings.PageLoadTimeoutSeconds);

InternetExplorerOptions IeOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions()
{
    InitialBrowserUrl = m_WebPageUrl,
    IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
    BrowserAttachTimeout = pageLoadTimeout,
    RequireWindowFocus = true,
    IgnoreZoomLevel = true
};

m_Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, IeOptions);

m_Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout);
m_Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(pageLoadTimeout);            
m_Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(pageLoadTimeout);

result = m_Driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId)).Text;
```

Throws this exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56732/session/4d8e064a-90b7-45f2-a7bc-42c7845534a4/element timed out after 60 seconds.
  Source=WebDriver
```

StackTrace:

```
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) 
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) 
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value) 
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id) in 
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context) 
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context) 
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by) 
       at Alpha.Dsm.WebPage.Utilities.WebPageInteractor.GetTableCellString(String cellId)
```

With an inner exception:

```
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The operation has timed out
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
```

Why does it not throw `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException` and how can I get it to?

Comment: Try setting [IE protected mode](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) to the same across the security zones, and setting `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings  = false`. Also, does your code work in earlier versions of IE?

Comment: This particular error has been covered a lot in the past: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3719 ...it appears that many things can cause it, but to begin with, **definitely** do as @Faiz said.

Comment: Also, is your `pageLoadTimeout` used for the `Timeouts()`, greater than 60secs, which is the default webdriver timeout? If so, I would think the webdriver will time out like it does now before the others.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I set     IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = false and am testing now.

Comment: Changing the Timeout to less than 60secs fixed the problem for IE. Thank you for your insight!